# Running code via an application

Tags: android

So I am trying to build a simple app which runs a code that is typed in.

For example "*#06#".

I thought this was supposed to be done by using `Intent.ACTION_CALL`, since you run the code by typing it into the phone keypad.

The "#" character isn't shown when the call is made so it doesn't work.

Is there some other `Intent` or another way of writing "#" so that this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*#60#"));
startActivity(intent);
```